# Cannot make a model @property def-as-field work with wagtail 2.0

Tags: wagtail

I'm using Wagtail 2.0 with a custom Block that has the following code:

```py
class LinkButtonBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    label = blocks.CharBlock()
    URL = blocks.CharBlock()
    styling = blocks.ChoiceBlock(
        choices=[
            ('btn-primary', 'Primary button'),
            ('btn-secondary', 'Secondary button'),
            ('btn-success', 'Success button'),
            ('btn-info', 'Info button'),
            ('btn-warning', 'Warning button'),
            ('btn-error', 'Error button'),
        ],
        default='btn-info',
    )
    outline = blocks.BooleanBlock(
        default=False
    )

    @property
    def css(self):
        btn_class = self.styling
        if self.outline is True:
            btn_class = btn_class.replace('btn-', 'btn-outline-')
            return btn_class

    class Meta:
        icon = 'link'
         template = 'testapp/blocks/link_button_block.html'
```

If I then try to access this `css` "property" in my template, nothing seems to happen. Putting a `print(self)` as first line inside the css def also shows nothing on the console suggesting the function never even gets called.

Using the following template:

```html
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

<a class="btn {{ block.value.css }}" href="{{ block.value.URL }}">{{ block.value.label }}</a>
```

Simply yields:

```html
<a class="btn " href="actual.url.from.instance">actual.label.from.instance</a>
```

Also, `block.value.styling` and `block.value.outline` on their own work just fine, so... what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The thing that's tripping you up is that the value objects you get when iterating over a `StreamField` are *not* instances of `StructBlock`. Block objects such as `StructBlock` and `CharBlock` act as converters between different data representations; they don't hold on to the data themselves. In this respect, they work a lot like Django's form field objects; for example, Django's `forms.CharField` and Wagtail's `CharBlock` both define how to render a string as a form field, and how to retrieve a string from a form submission.

Note that `CharBlock` works with string objects - not instances of `CharBlock`. Likewise, the values returned from `StructBlock` are not instances of `StructBlock` - they are a dict-like object of type `StructValue`, and *this* is what you need to subclass to implement your `css` property. There's an example of doing this in [the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/streamfield_blocks.html#additional-methods-and-properties-on-structblock-values). Applied to your code, this would become:

```py
class LinkButtonValue(blocks.StructValue):
    @property
    def css(self):
        # Note that StructValue is a dict-like object, so `styling` and `outline`
        # need to be accessed as dictionary keys
        btn_class = self['styling']
        if self['outline'] is True:
            btn_class = btn_class.replace('btn-', 'btn-outline-')
        return btn_class

class LinkButtonBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    label = blocks.CharBlock()
    URL = blocks.CharBlock()
    styling = blocks.ChoiceBlock(choices=[...])
    outline = blocks.BooleanBlock(default=False)

    class Meta:
        icon = 'link'
        template = 'testapp/blocks/link_button_block.html'
        value_class = LinkButtonValue
```